# Why Integer.getInteger does not work?

Tags: java, string, integer

I have the following code:

```
game.log.fine("HERE" + bestMove.get("score"));
Integer bestScore = Integer.getInteger(bestMove.get("score"));
game.log.fine("THERE" + bestScore);
```

As an output I have:

```
FINE: HERE50
Dec 9, 2010 11:34:17 AM game.Agent getCloud
FINE: THEREnull
Dec 9, 2010 11:34:17 AM game.Agent getCloud
```

Probably I had to add that bestMove is `HashMap<String,String>`.

The problem is that `bestMove.get("score")` gives a string value (equal to "50"). But if try to transform to integer, I get `null`.

Does anybody know what is the problem here?

Comment: Integer.parseInteger() instead? :)

Answer (score 38):

Because [`Integer.getInteger`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#getInteger(java.lang.String)) is not what you're searching for. From the Javadoc :

> Determines the integer value of the
>   system property with the specified
>   name. The first argument is treated as
>   the name of a system property. System
>   properties are accessible through the
>   System.getProperty(java.lang.String)
>   method. The string value of this
>   property is then interpreted as an
>   integer value and an Integer object
>   representing this value is returned.
>   Details of possible numeric formats
>   can be found with the definition of
>   getProperty.
>
> If there is no property with the
>   specified name, if the specified name
>   is empty or null, or if the property
>   does not have the correct numeric
>   format, then null is returned.

You want to use [`Integer.parseInt`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt(java.lang.String))

Comment: Brilliant function naming.

Answer (score 13):

I suspect that you're looking for the [`Integer.parseInt`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt%28java.lang.String%29) method:

> *Parses the string argument as a signed decimal integer.*

**Example usage:**

```
int bestScore = 0;
try {
    bestScore = Integer.parseInt(bestMove.get("score"));
} catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
    // handle exception gracefully
}
```

---

The [`Integer.getInteger`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#getInteger%28java.lang.String%29) does something completely different:

> *Determines the integer value of the system property with the specified name.*

Answer (score 10):

I would use the `Integer.valueOf(String n)` method.

```
Integer bestScore = Integer.valueOf(bestMove.get("score"));
```

From [this blog](http://konigsberg.blogspot.com/2008/04/integergetinteger-are-you-kidding-me.html), the reason they gave,

> `Integer.getInteger(String)` converts
>   a String to a number by assuming the
>   String is the name of a system
>   property numeric representation. In
>   other words.
>   `Integer.getInteger("12345")` is
>   likely to yield `null`.

Comment: Don't use `valueOf` internally it is `Integer.valueOf(parseInt(s, 10))' ... where `parserInt()` is nothing but `Integer.parseInt(String)` with radix **10**

Comment: @Favonius, true, hence it's essentially the same as `Integer.parseInt(s, 10)`. I would still suggest `valueOf()` since the JVM uses it for autoboxing anyways. What I'm saying is, if it's there to use, use it.

Comment: I agree the JVM uses the valueOf but that is for `valueOf(int)`. Also the reason for using it in autoboxing is ` as it returns a Integer instance representing the specified int value. If a new Integer instance is not required, this method should generally be used in preference to the constructor Integer(int), as this method is likely to yield significantly better space and time performance by caching frequently requested values.` - Taken from javadoc

Comment: @Favonius, sorry...wrong example of use of `valueOf()`. Essentially, they are both the same (`valueOf()`, `parseInt()`), so it's user preference.

Answer (score 4):

You should use

```
Integer.parseInt
```

in your code since

```
Integer.getInteger
```

will determine the integer value of the system property with the specified name.

Correct code would be:

```
Integer bestScore = Integer.parseInt(bestMove.get("score"), 10);
```

That `10` as the second arguments is the radix. Use it always so your number won't be parsed ambigously.

Comment: the second argument to `parseInt` can be omitted.

Comment: @aioobe: true, but I'd use it anyway, just to be safe.

Comment: Safe about what? The default is 10. They're not going to change it on us. And there nothing ambiguous about it either.

Comment: @aioobe, @EJP: guys, you were both right. Ghosts of Javascript must have haunted me because `parseInt()` there will treat `034` and `34` differently; first as octal, second as decimal, if you don't explicitly specify the radix.

Answer (score 4):

**Basic `Integer.getInteger`:**

The [`java.lang.Integer.getInteger(String nm, int val)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#getInteger%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) method determines **the integer value of the system property with the specified name**.The argument *val* is the *default value*.
  An
*Integer object* that represents the value of the *second argument* is returned if there is *no property* of the specified name, if the property does not have the correct *numeric format*, or if the specified name is *empty* or *null*.

Or

The [`java.lang.Integer.getInteger(String nm)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#getInteger%28java.lang.String%29) Determines the integer value of the *system property* with the specified name. The argument is treated as the *name of* a system property.  The string value of this property is then interpreted as an integer value and an Integer object representing this value is returned. **If there is *no property* with the specified name, if the specified name is *empty or null*, or if the property does *not have* the *correct numeric format*, then *null* is returned.**

**Note:** System properties are accessible through the `System.getProperty(java.lang.String)` method.

---

**Solution to Use:**( `Integer.parseInt` / `Integer.valueOf` )

The [`java.lang.Integer.parseInt(String s)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt%28java.lang.String%29) parses the string argument as a signed *decimal integer*. The characters in the string
**must** all be *decimal digits*, except that the first character may be an `ASCII` minus sign `'-' ('\u002D')` to *indicate a negative value*. The resulting integer value is returned, exactly as if the argument and the radix 10 were given as arguments to the `parseInt(java.lang.String, int)` method.

Or

The [`java.lang.Integer.valueOf(String s)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#valueOf%28java.lang.String%29) returns an Integer object *holding* the value of the *specified String*. The argument is interpreted as representing a *signed decimal integer*, exactly as if the argument were given to the `parseInt(java.lang.String)` method. The result is an *Integer object* that represents the integer value specified by the string.
In other words, this method returns an Integer object equal to the value of:

```
new Integer(Integer.parseInt(s))
```