# NullPointerException when reading text from a JTextField

Tags: java, swing

I'm doing a simple Javax.swing program, but there's some errors I really don't get. Here's the full code:

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.Color;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class JFrameColore extends JFrame
{
public JFrameColore()
{
    this.setSize(600, 300);

    label_R = new JLabel();
    label_R.setText("R");

    label_G = new JLabel();
    label_G.setText("G");

    label_B = new JLabel();
    label_B.setText("B");

    text_R = new JTextField();
    text_G = new JTextField();
    text_B = new JTextField();

    button_COLORA = new JButton();

    Azusa azunyan = new Azusa();

    button_COLORA.addActionListener(azunyan);

    panel_COLORE = new JPanel();


    label_COLORA = new JLabel();

}

public final JLabel label_R, label_G, label_B;

public final JTextField text_R, text_G, text_B;

public final JButton button_COLORA;

public final JPanel panel_COLORE;

public final JLabel label_COLORA;

private class Azusa implements ActionListener
{

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        boolean colorable = true;
        if (!isNumber(text_R.getText()))
        {
            colorable = false;
            text_R.setText("ERR");
        }
        else if (Integer.getInteger(text_R.getText()) < 0
                || Integer.getInteger(text_R.getText()) > 255)
        {
            colorable = false;
            text_R.setText("ERR");
        }
        if (!isNumber(text_G.getText()))
        {
            colorable = false;
            text_G.setText("ERR");
        }
        else if (Integer.getInteger(text_G.getText()) < 0
                || Integer.getInteger(text_G.getText()) > 255)
        {
            colorable = false;
            text_G.setText("ERR");
        }
        if (!isNumber(text_B.getText()))
        {
            colorable = false;
            text_B.setText("ERR");
        }
        else if (Integer.getInteger(text_B.getText()) < 0
                || Integer.getInteger(text_B.getText()) > 255)
        {
            colorable = false;
            text_B.setText("ERR");
        }



        if (colorable)
        {
            panel_COLORE.setOpaque(true);
            panel_COLORE.setBackground(new Color(

                    Integer.getInteger(text_R.getText()),
                    Integer.getInteger(text_G.getText()), 
                    Integer.getInteger(text_B.getText())
            ));
        }

    }

}

protected boolean isNumber(String gringo)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < gringo.length(); i++)
    {
        if (!Character.isDigit(gringo.charAt(i)))
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

}
```

For example, when I do 
`else if (Integer.getInteger(text_R.getText()) < 0
                    || Integer.getInteger(text_R.getText()) > 255)`

I get a NullPointerException, I really don't know why since I checked the values to be integer. What am I doing wrong? It would be nice for someone who's more experienced in Swing to explain.

Answer (score 1):

You want to do `Integer.parseInt()` instead of `Integer.getInteger()`:

```
else if (Integer.parseInt(text_R.getText())
```

[oracle docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html)

Here is a SO post explaining what `getInteger()` does - [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15411117/4028085)

Comment: Hell, I don't know how I mistook getInteger for parseInt. Don't know what I was thinking, thanks.